# Trying to mount unmounted 900gb

Tags: partitioning

I have some experience with mounting drives in linux, but I have never seen a setup like the one at my work.

Here is the lsblk

[image]

I can see that there is a 1.1tb part on sda3 but only 200 is being used, and I am trying to mount the 900 that is left, any help?

Comment: if there is no filesystem on the rest of the 900 GB, you can't mount it. You can create a filesystem (under LVM) and then mount that, I guess

Comment: "but I have never seen a setup like the one at my work." is it your machine? did you install it? If not... let the admin deal with this ;-)  It is an LVM so normal commands do not apply. And do make a backup :)

Comment: unfortunately the person who set it up no longer works here so I get to sort out everything. The person who set it up was a professional company who is not very professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is using LVM (Logical Volume Manager).
That 200GB is a logical volume (ubuntu-lv) that is part of the volume group (ubuntu-vg)

You can use `vgs` to list the volume groups, `lvs` to list the logical volumes.

To extend the volume you'll have to first extend the lvm volume (using `lvextend`) and then the filesystem

You can read more here https://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/extendlv.html

Example:
`lvextend --resizefs -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`